# What is "state=start"?

Tags: context

Throughout ConTeXt's web site and documentation, there are [examples](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=state&go=Go) that have `state=start`. The [reference manual](http://pmrb.free.fr/contextref.pdf) also has this, but it isn't clear to me what this means. In the manual, for different commands, it can take the value of `start`, `stop`, `keep`, `none`, `high`, `empty`, `none`, `nomarking`, etc.

Can someone clarify?

Comment: Which command are you referring to?  Not all commands take `state` as an argument.

Comment: BTW, the reference manual is not a good resource, see my comments here: https://github.com/hmenke/context-examples/blob/master/GUIDE.md#further-resources

Comment: Hi @HenriMenke, I just saw it everywhere, but didn't have specific commands in mind. How about `\setupinteraction[state=start]` and `\setupcolors[state=start]`? Another one I saw was `\definelogo`. I assumed that since it is such a common property, it had similar meanings everywhere.

Comment: `\setupcolors[state=start]` is not necessary in MkIV.  Colors are enabled by default.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `state` property is usually associated with global properties of the document.  Take for example

```
\setupinteraction[state=start]
```

This enables document interaction (hyperlinks).  If you wanted to switch it off (maybe only temporarily), you'd use

```
\setupinteraction[state=stop]
```

Searching in the [ConTeXt command reference](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/qrcs/setup-en.pdf) for `state =` gives me 46 matches.  Most of them are for some internal commands or on commands where `state=start` is the default.

---

In the second part you asked about what it means for `state` to be something other than `start` or `stop`.  I could find this for `\setuplayouttext` where you have

```
state = start stop empty high none normal nomarking NAME
```

To be honest, I have no idea what these mean, because I have never used this command directly and there seems to be no documentation on the Wiki.  There is documentation for [`\setupheader`](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setupheader) (for which I never used the `state` property) which is implemented in terms of `\setuplayouttext`.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe as addition to [Henri Menke's nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/461516/124577): There are cases where start and stop might not have the meaning you would expect, e.g. when talking about layers (from the [wiki](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Layers)):

> The available options for the "state" of a layer are:
>
> - start: layer appears only on the current page
> - stop: layer doesn't show up
> - repeat: layer prints on all pages
> - next: layer appears on the following page
> - continue: layer appears on all pages except the first

In one of your comments you are asking about `\setupcolors`. The wiki page tells you that it accepts four states: `local`, `global`, `start` and `stop`. In MkIV colors are enabled by default and only accept the states `start` and `stop` (see setup-en.pdf and sources).

This is just to exemplify that you should always check (and never fully trust) the documentation. If something is unclear, just ask a question, there will be people helping you :)